# Angular: How to change child element height

Tags: css, angular

Currently I have a layout like so

```
    <parent-comp>
       <child1> </child1>
       <child2> </child2>
    </parent-comp>
```

Parent component have fixed height ( 1000px )
Child 1 have 2 states: Expanded( 200px ) and Collapsed( 10px )
I would like to use these information to calculate and update child2's height accordingly

I do not want to set child2's height to auto ( I need a specific value since this is the requirement to pass it into another library (the virtual scroll) )

How can I achieve this?

I tried ViewChild + ElementRef to get child component's height from parent component but it seems to cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when I try to update the child component's height

Should the child component output it's current height to the parent or the parent should read it from it's child?

Comment: can you put your code on stackblitz so we can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. You need to `Output` the value from child to parent and propagate it to desired components and do your calculations.
Here's [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5az8c). 
If you want to pass this change of height to `Components` other than the children  then I would suggest you use a SharedService to subscribe and make changes to the value(s). Siblings or not, this way you can share data between multiple components.

If you just want to update the height, using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [Grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Sid 
I would like to set the height to a specific value due to a specific height is needed as input to another library ( virtual scroll )
The approach of child element reporting the value for itself works
It just that I feel a little bit strange to design a component that Output something like a current height...

Answer (score 4):

instead of doing it the hard way, you can simply use flex-box, which would take care of doing all the calculations for you.

e.g

```
.parent {
   display:Flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   height: 1000px;
}

.child1 {
/*  expanded */
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.collapsed {
  flex: 0 0 2%;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

you can apply collapsed classed dynamically with the help of ngclass, hope this helps.

If you want to learn more about flexbox play these free game at https://flexboxfroggy.com/ Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rajput
I would like to set the height to a specific value due to a specific height is needed as input to another library ( virtual scroll )

Comment: Precalculate it, e.g if parent's height is fixed assuming 1000px, child height when expanded is flex: 0 0 20% i.e(height  200px), child height when collapsed = 0 0 2% i.e(height = 20px)

Comment: Off-topic (sorry) - this frog game is very helpful. Thanks!